# vi: How do I save without exiting the editor?

Tags: vi

Any way to save changes in vi without exiting the editor? I'm experimenting with php and checking my work in the browser. To get back to my code I have to reopen the php file which is an extra step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:w`  to save

`:q`  to quit

`:q!` to quit in spite of unsaved changes

I'm assuming that you are asking becasue you have been using combination of the two `:wq`

Comment: Actually I have been using :x. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 4):

These commands operate only on the current buffer:

`:write`, or `:w` to save

`:update`, or `:up` to save only if changes were made (vim only)

`:wq` to save (current buffer only) and quit

`:exit`, or `:x` to save (current buffer only), but only if changes were made, then quit

These all have 'force' variants, e.g. `:wq!`, to write the current buffer and quit, even if other buffers contain unsaved changes.

Multiple buffers:

`:wall`, or `:wa` to write all buffers which have changed (vim only)

`:wqall`, or `:wqa` to write all changed buffers, then quit (vim only)

Shortcuts:

The key sequence `ZZ` in normal mode is a shortcut for `:exit`

The key sequence `ZQ` in normal mode is a shortcut for `:q!` (vim only)

Answer (score 2):

```
:w filename
```

This will write to that specified filename.

... useful when you're trying to track changes and not overwrite.